# unknown attribute 'type' for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I'm running a background job in rails that creates images and adds them to a gallery. Later the image can be added to other galleries so it's natural to have a has_many_through relationship between those two.

When the job reaches the lines below, I get the error:

```
unknown attribute 'type' for GalleryImages.
```

I'm not using any attribute 'type' so I guess the problem lies either in the way I use rails or something completely of my mind. Hope you guys could help me out with this issue.

relevant gems

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
```

job.rb

```
class Job < Struct.new(:museum_id)
    def perform
        puts "starting bg job"
        museum = Museum.find(museum_id)
        begin
            gallery = museum.gallery.create(name: 'somename', description: 'some virtual museum',)
        rescue => e
            puts e
        end
        path = '/home/parrot/pic.png'
        puts path
        md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(path))
        puts md5
        begin
            image = Image.create!(path: path, md5: md5) # create! raises an exception if validation fails
            gallery.images << image
        rescue => e
            puts e.message
            puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
        end
    end
end
```

gallery_image.rb

```
class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    belongs_to :image
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gallery_images, :class_name => 'GalleryImage'
  has_many :galleries, through: :gallery_images
  validates :path, :md5, presence: true
  validates :md5, uniqueness: true
end
```

gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :museum
  has_many :gallery_images, :class_name => 'GalleryImage'
  has_many :images, through: :gallery_images
end
```

20160427100528_create_gallery_images migration

```
class CreateGalleryImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :gallery_images, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :gallery, index: true
      t.belongs_to :image, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160427100528) do

  create_table "delayed_jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "attempts",   default: 0, null: false
    t.text     "handler",                null: false
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.string   "locked_by"
    t.string   "queue"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "delayed_jobs", ["priority", "run_at"], name: "delayed_jobs_priority"

  create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "md5"
    t.string   "path"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "gallery_images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
    t.integer  "image_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "gallery_images", ["image_id"], name: "index_gallery_images_on_image_id"
  add_index "gallery_images", ["gallery_id"], name: "index_gallery_images_on_gallery_id"

  create_table "galleries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "name"
    t.integer  "description"
    t.integer  "museum_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "museum_galleries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "gallery_id"
    t.integer "museum_id"
  end

  create_table "museums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
end
```

e.backtrace

```
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:566:in `init_attributes'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:141:in `build_association'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:250:in `build_record'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:146:in `build'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:95:in `build_through_record'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:117:in `save_through_record'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:66:in `insert_record'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:563:in `block (2 levels) in concat_records'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:408:in `replace_on_target'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:403:in `add_to_target'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:562:in `block in concat_records'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:560:in `each'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:560:in `concat_records'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:180:in `concat_records'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:44:in `concat_records'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:168:in `block in concat'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:183:in `block in transaction'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:182:in `transaction'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:168:in `concat'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:38:in `concat'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:970:in `<<'
/home/parrot/learn-rails/onlinemuseum/app/jobs/job.rb:24:in `perform'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:100:in `block in invoke_job'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:97:in `invoke_job'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/parrot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:89:in `block in timeout'
/home/parrot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `call'
/home/parrot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:224:in `block in run'
/home/parrot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:223:in `run'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:300:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:300:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:207:in `block in work_off'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:206:in `times'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:206:in `work_off'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:169:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/home/parrot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:168:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:167:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:166:in `loop'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:166:in `block in start'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/worker.rb:165:in `start'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:131:in `run'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:119:in `block in run_process'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `block in start_proc'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:274:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:274:in `start_proc'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:295:in `start'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/controller.rb:59:in `run'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons.rb:193:in `block in run_proc'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:117:in `run_process'
/home/parrot/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:93:in `daemonize'
./bin/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have table name as `:gallery_images`, yuor model should be called as `GalleryImage`, so if:

```
create_table :gallery_images, id: false do |t|
```

rename the model and file name to:

**app/models/gallery_image.rb**:

```
class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Or do vice-versa: model name `GalleryImages` and table name `:gallery_imageses`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did what you sad and got "uninitialized constant Page::PageImages" which I fixed by renaming all :class_name => 'PageImages' to 'PageImage'. Once that was done I got again "unknown attribute 'type' for PageImage."

Comment: I did a "bundle exec rake db:reset db:migrate" between all changes (and restarted rails) if thats relevant...

Comment: You should generate new models like : `rails g model PageImage` it will generate migration file along with model file.

Comment: @parrotsarecool between updated do : `db:drop db:create db:migrate`. then after that show your `db/schema.db` in part of the related tables

Comment: @parrotsarecool and have you any descendants for class `PageImage` ?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ i added schema.rb to OP and PageImage has no descendants

Comment: @parrotsarecool where is table page_images? if your model PageImage is inherited from GalleryImage, it will require type file since you have enabled STI for the table.

Comment: Yuck sorry, I always do a sample application for myself if I encounter a problem to solve it. I copied the error message from the wrong terminal window (in this case I wanted to avoid more naming issues concerning the plural form of gallery). So page is really a synonym for gallery. But the errors stay the same in both cases.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ thank you for your patience. I edited OP in order to reflect my changes. The error stays the same.

Comment: I've added the trace log generated by e.backtrace at the rescue of the lines in question.

Comment: @parrotsarecool what is the code around here `/home/parrot/learn-rails/onlinemuseum/app/jobs/job.rb:24:in `perform'`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ added full job.rb, the code creates a gallery, an image and tries to associate those two.

Comment: @parrotsarecool have you exactly changed  GalleryImages to  GalleryImage ? if yes, I dont know why it still throws invalid field of  type... may be you have runned something like spring what caches old models etc.... In that caases I just put into rails sources `binding.pry` from `pry` gem and hardly debug...

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the problem with the help of a more experienced student and it turned out that my environment was broken. After cleaning that up everything worked fine.